# Combining two Pandas series indexes into one

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, series

So I have the following series:

```
small car        285
midsize car      138
small SUV        108
large car         88
standard SUV      86
pickup            78
station wagon     34
minivan            5
```

I want to combine *'small SUV'* and *'standard SUV'* into one index named *'SUV'* with their sum, like this:

```
small car        285
midsize car      138
SUV              194
large car         88
pickup            78
station wagon     34
minivan            5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.contains` with `np.where` for assignment of new value `SUV` , then calculate sum on level=0

```
c = s.index.str.contains("SUV") #s is the variable name of the series here
s.index = np.where(c,"SUV",s.index)
s.sum(level=0)
```

---

```
small car        285
midsize car      138
SUV              194
large car         88
pickup            78
station wagon     34
minivan            5
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This worked like magic!, but can you explain the sum(level=0) part please?

Comment: @YoussefAlaaEtman you can interpret it like `s.groupby(s.index).sum()` here

Comment: Can I now reorder the series so the SUV is above the midsize car?

Comment: @YoussefAlaaEtman do you have a fixed list of indexes? if not , is there any logic or just an edge case where you want to push SUV above midsize car? does midsize car always exist? few questions :)